# Retrieving the highest value from list

Tags: development, splistitem, splist

My question is regarding retrieving a value from a sharepoint list. Basically I have a list with some data. One of the fields in the list is a text field with numbers.

So what i want to do, i want to retrieve the highest number from that field ... how can i do that most practical and with best approach?

This will be done programmatically.

Of course i couuld do a loop through all the items, but i would like to avoid looping, is there a better way?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Programatically use SPQuery and in your caml query use the OrderBy Node

eg:

```
<Query><OrderBy><FieldRef Name="yourcolumn" Ascending="True" /></OrderBy></Query>
```

You can also set the RowLimit property of SPQuery to 1 to make it more efficient

Hope this helps

UPDATE:
As Nadeem Yousuf mentioned on another answer, this will not work with a text field, so might need to consider changing the type of this column (if possible?)

Comment: nah, can't change it directly ... so no any other practical approaches for it?

Comment: did you know that if the data are all number you could change the type without losing any data?. Unfortunately I am not aware of another way to do it without looping though all the items. Wonder if you can use this guys http://camlex.codeplex.com/ and casting to an int in the lambda query

Answer (score 0):

Had the field in question been a Number field, I would have done Order By desc on that and put the RowLimit of SPQuery to 1. But I am not sure whether Ordery By clause will work here as yours is a text field containing numbers.